# Blazor NavigationManager not working with NavigateTo

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Here's how i inject navigationmanager:

```
 [Inject]
public NavigationManager navigationManager { get; set; }
```

and this is the method where i need to use navigation manager to navigato to home page:

```
 protected async Task LoginMethod()
{
    authResult = await AuthenticationService.Login(new Models.Dtos.Requests.UserLoginRequest()
    {
        Email = Email,
        Password = Password
    });
    Token = authResult.Token;
    navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
}
```

I don't really know why but NavigationManager.NavigateTo doesn't work

Comment: If nothing appears to happen, then it is likely an error is being thrown in your LoginMethod before NavigateTo can be called - wrap the code in a try...catch and see if that is why

Comment: Still nothing but the interesting thing is that if i go in debug mode, NavigateTo method gets executed but without nothing happening.

Comment: @Leo, if works if you remove the backend `Login` call? Be sure to enclose backend call in a `try catch` as MrMagoo saw and manage exceptions.

Comment: Solved by changing from an async task to an async void

Comment: I would be hesitant to use 'async void' as this is generally seen as bad practice - (https://vishalkhatal.wordpress.com/2018/08/04/async-void-vs-async-task-in-asynchronous-programming/). There maybe a better answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373003/navigationmanager-navigateto-in-razor-pages-c-sharp-sometimes-dont-work).

Comment: LOL! I changed from async Void OnLogin to async Task OnLogin and it worked. I also added this.StateHasChanged(); after NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");